# Present SLComposeViewController for SLServiceTypeFacebook results in "Not Logged In" alert when user is logged in through Settings > Facebook on iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

**Question**

Am I setting up and calling the SLComposeViewController correctly? (please see code below)

My understanding is that irrespective of whether the user successfully logs into Facebook through the Facebook app or device Settings > Facebook the SLComposeViewController should be accessible to the end user.

**Observed**

Instead, what I observe is the following:

1. **Fails:** An attempt to present SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook) results in the display of a "Not Logged In" alert on top of the SLComposeViewController. This happens when the Facebook App is installed on an iOS 8 device and the user is already logged in through device Settings > Facebook. The exact text of the alert is "Not Logged In You need to be logged into the Facebook app in order to post to Facebook. Please log into the Facebook app and try again. [OK]" When the user selects the OK button in the alert the SLComposeViewController is dismissed.
2. **Succeeds:** However, if the user logs out from Settings > Facebook and logs in through the Facebook app, then the SLComposeViewController is displayed correctly. (The “Not Logged In” alert is not displayed.)
3. **Succeeds:** Further, If the Facebook app is removed from the device and the user logs in through device Settings > Facebook then the SLComposeViewController is displayed correctly.
4. **Succeeds:** If the user logs into Facebook through device Settings > Facebook on the iOS simulator then the SLComposeViewController is displayed correctly.

**Versions**

- Facebook 37.0.0.21.273
- iOS 8.4
- iPhone 6

**Swift Code**

```
func postToFacebook(parentViewController: UIViewController, favoriteText: String) {

    if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook) {
        var composeController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)

        // set initial text
        var text = String(format:"My favorite is %@ ", favoriteText)
        composeController.setInitialText(text)

        // set image
        let logoImage = UIImage(named: "AppIcon40x40") as UIImage!
        composeController.addImage(logoImage!)

        // set url
        let nsURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.myappdomainhere.com")
        composeController.addURL(nsURL)

        // display the social view controller
        parentViewController.presentViewController(composeController, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }
    else {
        let messageString = "My own error string here"
        let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Facebook Account Required", message: messageString, delegate: parentViewController, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")
        alert.show()
    }
}
```

**Note**

The SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType call succeeds in the above code.

Comment: It seems that you already created a bug report for this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/681911911908878/.